# Python Scrapy - (403) status code is not handled or not allowed

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, user-agent, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to scrape reviews from Tripadvisor, more specifically from this [address](https://www.tripadvisor.it/Restaurant_Review-g187791-d25150423-Reviews-Don_s_Meats_Spirits-Rome_Lazio.html).

I'm currently unable to scrape any data and I'm returned the 403 status code. At first I tried the usual command `scrape crawl reviews` without success. I then tried to make some tests with `scrape shell 'website address'` and received the same 403 status. Any *extract()* attempt returns an empty array.

I've looked up some guides online and installed [scrapy-user-agents](https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-user-agents/) and inserted the correct *Downloader Middlewares* in the *settings.py* file as indicated in the linked page. The scraper now tries to crawl the website with a set of fake user-agents but for each one of them I get the error:

`[scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedBrowserType]`

or the error:

`[scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType]`

and 0 pages are crawled.

Anyone with some experience in scraping Tripadvisor has any idea on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting a static user-agent in the *settings.py* file. Scrapy already offers a sample for this but it is commented. I just uncommented it:

`USER_AGENT = "reviewscraper (+http://www.yourdomain.com)"`